# React Native Video Exo Player causes app to restart when send to background

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

I am using react-native-video package to display video.  Below is my code :

```
  <Video
  paused={paused}
  source={{ uri: gallery.path }}
  style={{ width, height: 280 }}
  resizeMode="contain"
  bufferConfig={{
    minBufferMs: 2600,
    maxBufferMs: 30000,
    bufferForPlaybackMs: 2500,
    bufferForPlaybackAfterRebufferMs: 2000,
  }}
  ref={ref}
  onEnd={() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.seek(0);
    }
  }}
/>;
```

This is a part of the screen under Tab Navigator and Stack Navigator.  I have 2 issues:

1. The video does not stop when I move the app to the background. I was able to do it using `AppState` and setting paused to true when `AppState !=== "active"`. Wouldn't the player automatically stop it?
2. When the app is moved to the background - sometimes the app restarts. This is happening non-deterministically and I can't find much logs in logcat nor does my sentry report anything.

This page is called IndividualGalleryScreen.tsx

I also have a `DashboardScreen.tsx` on a different tab which has multiple such Video Elements in a FlatList.

I am not using android.largeHeap=true

Can anyone guide me on what could be the issue that app sometimes restarts when I try to get it to the foreground?

Thank you.